# How precise are Google Chrome extension statistics?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I published a Chrome Extension, but statistics are weird. At first, I realized that it doesn't count inline installation on my custom webpage.

- Do you think that Total Current Users is precise?
- For some days I have bigger drop of Total Current Users than number of uninstallations, which is nonsense.

**Is there any way how to get precise statistics of total users, installations and uninstallations?**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure is how precise stats in the current version of Developer Dashboard. But I know that Google working on a new version and it is already in closed-beta testing. 

The new one has more detailed stats about installation sources.

Here also some steps that can help to improve your stats counting:

1. Add Google Analytics tracking ID to your Chrome Web Store item;
2. Track ['successCallback'](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#triggering) event on the extensions promo website;
3. Open a "welcome" page, hosted on your website – so you can count those who just installed the extension. Docs: [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled);
4. Open a "good bye" page, after users remove your extension from a browser. So you can calc uninstall events. One more benefit - you can ask "what was wrong?". Docs: [chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL).

*Updated.*