# Google Analytics vs. Chrome Web Store Statistics Very Different

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, chrome-web-store, usage-statistics

I recently released a chrome extension new tab, and I wanted to check the download/usage statistics.

I added both google analytics and checked the chrome web store stats. The values are extremely different. Here they are (for the same app):

[image: web store]
[image: analytics]

Here is my extension on the web store: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perspective-new-tab/hehnfhfmcifhbgkefjbfbaefhddlpnjj

My question: why are these values so different? They are off by a factor of 10. Which one (if any) is correct, and is there some way I can know for sure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307771/chrome-extension-stats-not-updating), sometimes it takes many days for stats to show, and some days are never updated.

> ***If you link your extension with google analytics, you can then see installs from analytics but its not the same, as the chrome stats also substract uninstalls (not tracked in analytics).***

You may also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330359/how-precise-are-google-chrome-extension-statistics) for additional reference.